# Nuxt 3 middleware returns 404

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, middleware, nuxtjs3

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 app that displays articles. It's a new versions of an existing React app. In the old React app the url format for article was [www.mysite.com/id-of-categories/title-of-article](http://www.mysite.com/id-of-categories/title-of-article) but in the Nuxt one it's simply [www.mysite.com/posts/title-of-article](http://www.mysite.com/posts/title-of-article).

The issues is that in many articles an url that points to another article of the site is written inside the body article ( there is more than 700 articles, so I don't want to spend a week to rewrite the URLS) but these old links could work if I could just replace the /id-of-category/ for /posts/ in the URL.

I tried to set up a global middleware but this does not work, either the middlewrae is not triggered and the page returns 404 ( as expect, the URL does not change) or it renders an infinite loop that kills my computer.

I can't use anonymous or named middleware because articles are not rendered in the /pages directory of Nuxt. In the end I just need Nuxt to "detect" if the URL format is wrong and returns the good one. Also categories ID can range from 01 to 30. Theses links can only be seen in article body, nowhere else

Here is my middleware, where I try to remove the four first items ( in the case of the middleware the four first items will always be the categories I mentioned, from  /01/ to /30/, and then replace the old category with /posts/ and returns that

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
 
  if (to.fullPath.includes("/17/")) {
// 17 is for testing, it can be anything between /01/ to /30/
    const newArticleTitle = to.path.substring(4);
    // Redirect to the new URL format
 
    return navigateTo(`/posts/${newArticleTitle}`);
  }
});
```

thanks

tried middleware, anonymous function on click of inner link in article template.vue

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your navigator inside of page components instead of global middleware

---

create a new page component in your pages folder like below

```
| /
|- pages
|  |- [category_id]
|     |-[article_title].ts
```

then, define the navigator in the `/pages/[category_id]/[article_title].ts`

```js
const { data: article } = await useFetch(
    `__THE_RESTful_SHOW_API_OF_YOUR_ARTICLES__`,
);

navigateTo(`/posts/${article.title}`);
```

---

ps: use `/posts/{post_id}/{post_title}` may be a better practice than `/posts/{post_title}`

1. the `{post_title}` may have duplicates
2. using the primary key could be faster in DB operation
3. they have almost the same SEO effect